# Redux Form Selecting form value

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I need to validate the birthday with respect to the month and Year. If feb than birthday will not be greater than 28. If month are even number than birthday will not will greater than 30, if Odd month, birthday will not be greater than 31, and in leap year birthday will not be greater than 29. I have set the validation for all possible condition. Now I have to get the value from the redux store on selecting month. This is legacy code and example show for the Selecting from value in redux form website example confusing me with this code. I need to fetch the value from the redux store in this code so that i can put that in a condition to validate the birthday on given condition.

```
import React, { PureComponent, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import moment from 'moment';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { FaVenus as FemaleIcon, FaMars as MaleIcon } from 'react-icons/lib/fa/';
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import { Field, reduxForm, actions } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { TextInput, Select } from 'components/Fields';

import * as rules from 'utils/validationRules';
import * as DateValidator from 'utils/DateValidator';
import { DOB_RAW_FORMAT, PERSON_TYPE_CLIENT, PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER, HOUSEHOLD_SINGLE, birthMonth } from 'containers/constants';
import { selectDobOfClientAndPartner, selectPostalCodeLookup } from '../selectors';
import { doValidatePostalCode, clearPostalCodeLookup } from '../actions';

// const FORM_NAME = 'advisor-feeForm';

// const selector = formValueSelector(FORM_NAME);

export const SexOptions = [
  { value: 'female', label: 'Female', icon: <FemaleIcon /> },
  { value: 'male', label: 'Male', icon: <MaleIcon /> },
];

let dobValues = null;
let personType = '';
const AGE_OFFSET = 30;
let showPostalCodeInfo = false;
const CLIENT_FORM = 'clientForm';

const dobDiffValidator = (dobVals, householdType, dob) => {
  let diffDob = null;
  if (dobVals && dobVals.householdType !== HOUSEHOLD_SINGLE && (dobVals.partner || dobVals.client)) {
    if (householdType === PERSON_TYPE_CLIENT) {
      diffDob = dobVals.partner || dob;
    } else if (householdType === PERSON_TYPE_PARTNER) {
      diffDob = dobVals.client || dob;
    }
    return DateValidator.validateDobDiff(diffDob, dob, 'years', AGE_OFFSET, householdType);
  }
  return null;
};

const doValidateDob = (formProps) => {
  const date = moment.utc(formProps.toJS().DOB, DOB_RAW_FORMAT, true);
  const errors = {};
  if (dobValues && personType && date) {
    errors.DOB = dobDiffValidator(dobValues, personType, date);
  }
  return errors;
};

const normalizePostalCode = (value) => {
  const postalCode = value.toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/, '');
  showPostalCodeInfo = false;
  if (!postalCode || postalCode.length !== 6) return value;

  return postalCode.substring(0, 3).concat(' ', postalCode.substring(3));
};

const OptionStandalone = ({ label, icon, value, onSelect, namePrefix, disabled }) => {
  const cn = disabled ? 'client-form__button--disabled client-form__button' : 'client-form__button';
  return (
    <button id={`${value}button`} onClick={() => onSelect(value)} type="button" className={cn}>
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};

class MaleOrFemale extends PureComponent {
  onChangeCombined = (val) => {
    const { input } = this.props;
    input.onChange(val);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <OptionStandalone
          {...SexOptions[1]}
          onSelect={this.onChangeCombined}
          disabled={this.props.input.value !== 'male'}
        />
        <OptionStandalone
          {...SexOptions[0]}
          onSelect={this.onChangeCombined}
          disabled={this.props.input.value !== 'female'}
        />
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const SexSelector = ({ onChange, active, namePrefix, captions }) => {
  const selector = (
    <Field
      name={`${namePrefix}sex`}
      component={MaleOrFemale}
      directOnChange={onChange}
      active={active}
      className="2"
      validate={[rules.required]}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="client-form__input">
      <div className="client-form__input-label" id="labelSex">
        <FormattedMessage {...captions.sexLabel} />
      </div>
      {selector}
    </div>
  );
};

**const BirhdayValidator = (validateAllDoB) => {
  if (birthMonth !== '2') {
    validateAllDoB = rules.birthDay;
  } else {
    validateAllDoB = rules.febBirthday;
  }
  return (
    <Field
      name={'birth_day'}
      type="tel" placeholder={'day'}
      component={TextInput}
      validate={[rules.required, validateAllDoB]}
    />
  );
};**

/* eslint react/no-multi-comp: 0 */
class ClientForm extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { initialValues } = props;

    this.state = {
      sex: initialValues.get('sex'),
      fNameFilled: false,
      lNameFilled: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const formName = this.props.form;
    dobValues = this.props.dobValues;
    personType = formName.substring(0, formName.indexOf('Form'));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearPostalCode();
  }

  handleFirstNameBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const isFilled = value.length > 0;
    this.setState({ fNameFilled: isFilled });
  };

  handleLastNameBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const isFilled = value.length > 0;
    this.setState({ lNameFilled: isFilled });
  };

  handleSexChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ sex: value });
  };

  handlePostalCodeOnBlur = (e) => {
    showPostalCodeInfo = false;
    const postalCode = String(e.target.value);
    if (postalCode) {
      const isInvalid = rules.postalCode(postalCode);
      if (!isInvalid) {
        showPostalCodeInfo = true;
        this.props.clearPostalCode();
        this.props.validatePostalCode(postalCode);
      }
    } else {
      // error...
    }
  };

  handleLastNameKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.handleLastNameBlur(e);
    }
  };

  incFieldsCount() {
    if (this.state.fieldsCount + 1 <= this.maxFieldsCount) {
      return { fieldsCount: this.state.fieldsCount + 1 };
    }
    return { fieldsCount: this.state.fieldsCount };
  }

  render() {
    const { captions, intl, namePrefix, postalCodeLookup, form } = this.props;
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="client-form-container">
        <h2>
          <FormattedMessage {...captions.header} />
        </h2>
        <form className="client-form">
          <div>
            <div className="client-form__input">
              <div className="client-form__input-label" id="labelClientFirstName">
                <FormattedMessage {...captions.nameLabel} />
              </div>
              <div className="client-form__input-field client-form__input-field__first-name">
                <Field
                  name={`${namePrefix}firstName`}
                  type="text"
                  component={TextInput}
                  placeholder={intl.formatMessage(captions.firstNamePlaceholder)}
                  validate={[rules.required]}
                  onBlur={this.handleFirstNameBlur}
                  ariaLabel={intl.formatMessage(captions.firstNamePlaceholder)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="client-form__input-label" id="labelClientLastName" />
              <div className="client-form__input-field client-form__input-field__last-name">
                <Field
                  name={`${namePrefix}lastName`}
                  type="text"
                  component={TextInput}
                  placeholder={intl.formatMessage(captions.lastNamePlaceholder)}
                  validate={[rules.required]}
                  onBlur={this.handleLastNameBlur}
                  onKeyPress={this.handleLastNameKeyPress}
                  ariaLabel={intl.formatMessage(captions.lastNamePlaceholder)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <SexSelector
              onChange={this.handleSexChange}
              value={state.sex}
              namePrefix={namePrefix}
              captions={captions}
            />
            <div className="client-form__input">
              <div className="client-form__input-label" id="labelDOB">
                <FormattedMessage {...captions.birthdayLabel} values={{ GENDER: state.sex || '' }} />
              </div>

              <div className="client-form__input-field client-form__input-field__birth-month">
                <Field
                  name={`${namePrefix}birth_month`}
                  label="month"
                  component={Select}
                  placeholder="Month"
                  validate={[rules.required]}
                  options={birthMonth}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="client-form__input-label" />
              <div className="client-form__input-field client-form__input-field__birth-day">
                {BirhdayValidator()}
              </div>

              <div className="client-form__input-label" />
              <div className="client-form__input-field client-form__input-field__birth-year">
                <Field
                  name={`${namePrefix}birth_year`}
                  type="tel" placeholder={'year'}
                  component={TextInput}
                  validate={[rules.required, rules.birthYear]}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {form === CLIENT_FORM && (
              <div className="client-form__input">
                <div className="client-form__input-label" id="labelPostalCode">
                  <FormattedMessage {...captions.postalCodeLabel} />
                </div>
                <div className="client-form__input-field">
                  <Field
                    name={`${namePrefix}postalCode`}
                    type="text"
                    component={TextInput}
                    placeholder="e.g. M1M 1M1"
                    normalize={normalizePostalCode}
                    validate={[rules.required, rules.postalCode]}
                    onBlur={this.handlePostalCodeOnBlur}
                    width="7em"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          {postalCodeLookup.isPostalCodeFound === false &&
          showPostalCodeInfo &&
          form === CLIENT_FORM && (
            <div>
              <div className="client-form__warning-label" name="label_postalCodeInfo">
                <FormattedMessage {...captions.postalCodeAllCanada} />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ClientForm.propTypes = {
  initialValues: PropTypes.object,
  captions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  intl: intlShape,
  namePrefix: PropTypes.string,
  form: PropTypes.string,
  dobValues: PropTypes.object,
  clearPostalCode: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  validatePostalCode: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  postalCodeLookup: PropTypes.object,
};

ClientForm.defaultProps = {
  namePrefix: '',
};
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  dobValues: selectDobOfClientAndPartner(),
  postalCodeLookup: selectPostalCodeLookup(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updateErrors: (formName, field, err, touched) => {
      if (touched) {
        dispatch(actions.blur(formName, field, '', touched));
      }
      return dispatch(actions.updateSyncErrors(formName, { [field]: err }));
    },
    validatePostalCode: (postalCode) => dispatch(doValidatePostalCode(postalCode)),
    clearPostalCode: () => dispatch(clearPostalCodeLookup()),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  reduxForm({ validate: doValidateDob })(injectIntl(ClientForm))
);
```

Comment: put your validation logic inside : doValidateDob

Answer (score 0):

To validate some field, that depends on others you can use `allValues` parameter passed in your validation function.

So you can write the specific rule for that field:

```
const validateDoB = (value, allValues) => {
  // For example allValues.birth_year is accessible here
}
```

And then write your `Field` component:

```
<Field
  name={'birth_day'}
  type="tel" placeholder={'day'}
  component={TextInput}
  validate={[rules.required, validateDoB]}
/>
```